# How to Loop through a If condition untill the user enter a required value, in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, loops, if-statement, console-application

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the number")
Dim number As Integer = Console.ReadLine()

If (number=< 40) Then
    number = number* 10
ElseIf (number=< 150) Then
    number= number* 15
Else
    number= number* 26
End If
Console.WriteLine(number)

Dim total As Integer
Dim vALUE As Integer

   Console.WriteLine("Please, type 1 for x . Type 2 for y. Type 3 z")
vALUE = Console.ReadLine()

If vALUE = 1 Then
    Console.WriteLine("x")
    total = number* (106 / 100)

ElseIf vALUE = 2
    Console.WriteLine("y")
    total = number* (112 / 100)

ElseIf uSERvALUE = 3
    Console.WriteLine("z")
    total = number* (116 / 100)

Else
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry please re-enter the value")
    vALUE = Nothing


End If
```

End While

Please tell me how to repeat the if condition. In the else line I have displayed to the user to re-enter the value. Therefore I need to repeat the if condition until the value is 1 or 2 or 3.Please explain how to do I'm a newbie.

Comment: Could you include your code in this post please?

Comment: Make a function and loop over that function. If the function returns a correct value, exit the loop.

Comment: can you please explain it more simply

Comment: can anybody tell a way to do it without making a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use infinite While-loop  ,and  put "Exit While" on the end of conditional statement you agreed , so there are few ways out from infinite loop.

For example , on your code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the number")
    Dim number As Integer = Console.ReadLine()

    If (number=< 40) Then
        number = number* 10
    ElseIf (number=< 150) Then
        number= number* 15
    Else
        number= number* 26
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(number)

    Dim total As Integer
    Dim vALUE As Integer

'infinite loop until user input 1,2 or 3
While True

    Console.WriteLine("Please, type 1 for x . Type 2 for y. Type 3 z")
    vALUE = Console.ReadLine()

    If vALUE = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine("x")
        total = number* (106 / 100)
        Exit While    'condition matched , break from While 
    ElseIf vALUE = 2
        Console.WriteLine("y")
        total = number* (112 / 100)
        Exit While    'condition matched , break from While 
    ElseIf uSERvALUE = 3
        Console.WriteLine("z")
        total = number* (116 / 100)
        Exit While    'condition matched , break from While 
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry please re-enter the value")
        vALUE = Nothing


    End If

End While

'do further more you need
```

Comment: The while loop covered "Console.WriteLine("Please, type 1 if the connection is a commercial type . Type 2 if the connection is a Resident type. Type 3 if the connection is a Special type")" , so that it would re-ask question.

Comment: give me second i'll re-check it again. last time i execute it, it didn't re-ask the question it just exits.

Comment: sorry dude my bad, it worked. great, thank you very much

Comment: I made some changes so it won't get me in a problem of Plagiarism in our university